Need VBA code to retrieve ALL data from a webpage
I’m trying to retrieve a list of attendees to an event on a webpage.  If I use a browser, to the webpage, right click, and choose View Page Source I can see the names of the attendees.
I need to do this with VBA.  I have tried 3 different properties (objIE.Document.body.innerText, objIE.Document.body.innerHTML, objIE.Document.body.textContent)  of the IE object and none return the attendee names.  Something is going on behind the scenes.  How do I fix this?
Public Sub OpenWebsiteAndRetrieveData()
    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim strPageContent As String
    Dim strinnerText As String
    Dim strinnerHTML As String
    Dim strTextContent As String
        
    ' Initialize the URL
    strURL = "https://meetup.com/cflfreethought/events/301401141/attendees/"
    
    ' Create an Internet Explorer instance
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    ' Navigate to the URL
    objIE.Navigate strURL
    
    ' Wait for the page to fully load
    Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    ' Make the Internet Explorer visible (optional)
    objIE.Visible = True
    
    ' Retrieve the inner text of the webpage
    
    strinnerText = objIE.Document.body.innerText
    strinnerHTML = objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
    strTextContent = objIE.Document.body.textContent
            
    ' Output the content (for demonstration purposes)
    Debug.Print "innerText:", Len(strinnerText), InStr(strinnerText, "David")
    Debug.Print "innerHTML:", Len(strinnerHTML), InStr(strinnerHTML, "David")
    Debug.Print "TextContent:", Len(strTextContent), InStr(strTextContent, "David")
        
    ' Clean up
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
    
    Stop
    
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub    


If I visit that URL it presents me with a login page. If you're not seeing that in you're browser then the site is maintaining a logged-in status which won't be emulated by your VB code unless you implement it yourself.

I didn't realize that.  I usually use the Chrome browser, so I visited the URL with Edge and I see what you mean.  Any idea how I would create/maintain a logged in status with VB?

You'll need to reverse engineer the login process to see what's going on. Look for one or more cookies being set. Different sites use different methods so there's no single way to do this, and if the site uses JavaScript your VB code won't work. Meetup has an API which might be easier if you meet their terms of use.

Note that reverse engineering the site and storing it's data in some other form are both explicitly against Meetup's Terms of Service.

Thank you for your help.  I'll look into the API.  I'm trying SeleniumBasic but having problems, getting an error message that it can't find the chrome binary, but I see it in: c:\program files\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe.
